# Issue using ng-class in angularJs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working in an application using angularJs and Bootstrap. I need to display the title of a 'scenario' but changing the Css depending on the status of the scenario and displaying a different icon.

In the beginning I tried this

```
<span class="text-success" data-ng-if="scenario.status=='success'"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Scenario {{scenario.title}}</span>
<span class="text-danger" data-ng-if="scenario.status=='fail'"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>Scenario {{scenario.title}}</span>
<span data-ng-if="scenario.status=='none'">Scenario {{scenario.title}}</span>
```

Which is working fine.
But I would like to do it in a more proper way and avoid the duplication of the code so I would like to use ng-class, I have modified the code as following:

```
 <span ng-class="{text-success:scenario.status=='success' || text-danger:scenario.status=='fail'}">Scenario {{scenario.title}}
                        <i ng-class="{fa fa-check-circle:scenario.status=='success' || fa fa-exclamation-circle:scenario.status=='fail'}"></i>
                        </span>
```

However this way is not working and I don't see what is the problem. Could someone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: `||`  syntax is wrong, you need an angular expression that return the classname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution is:

```
<span ng-class="{'text-success': scenario.status === 'success', 'text-danger': scenario.status === 'fail'}">
    Scenario {{scenario.title}}
    <i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-check-circle': scenario.status === 'success', 'fa-exclamation-circle': scenario.status === 'fail'}"></i>
</span>
```

> The ngClass directive allows you to dynamically set CSS classes on an
>   HTML element by databinding an expression that represents all classes
>   to be added.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getClassName = function() {
     return "text-" + scenario.status;      
}
```

Then binding:

```
ng-class="getClassName()"
```

Comment: i prefer to have logic in controller and not mixed in template, and this solution i more extensible to other kind of status